# Bundle with docker-compose installs gems from scratch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, bundle, bundler

I'm trying to cache bundle install on Docker build. 
I've tried recommendations from several blog posts and I ended up in something like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add build-base postgresql-dev nodejs git tzdata

ENV APP_HOME /panabus-api
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
ENV BUNDLE_PATH /gems
ENV GEM_PATH /gems
ENV GEM_HOME /gems

RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY . $APP_HOME

ENV RAILS_ENV=production

RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production assets:precompile apipie:cache

LABEL maintainer="Hari Carreras Pérez <hc@abtion.com>"

CMD bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  box:
    image: busybox
    volumes:
      - gem_cache:/gems

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.3-alpine
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always

  web:
    build: .
    image: panabus-api-web
    command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb -p 3000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - box
    volumes:
      - .:/panabus-api
      - gem_cache:/gems
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true

  setup:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - box
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - .:/panabus-api
      - gem_cache:/gems
    command: "bin/rails db:create db:migrate"
volumes:
  postgres:
  gem_cache:
```

This doesn't update the gems if the Gemfile hasn't changed. Unfortunately, if it has changed, it install all gems from scratch, not using the cache.

Is there any way to cache the gems on build?
I'd like to keep bundle in the Dockerfile since Heroku uses the same Dockerfile.

Comment: you could try to put the `RUN apk update` after you copy the gems... i dont know gems but you dont compile them right, it is just files... i would also suggest you use proper the alpine apk properly for smaller images with --virtual-deps, --no-cache, --update

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a tag to your bundle check where you have cached the installed gems

```
bundle check || bundle install --binstubs="$BUNDLE_BIN"
```

and cache the bundle with a specific path like so

```
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle \
  BUNDLE_BIN=/bundle/bin \
  GEM_HOME=/bundle
ENV PATH="${BUNDLE_BIN}:${PATH}"
```